# How to record “export as” as an action in Photoshop CC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, actions

I'm using Photoshop CC v20.0.7, and I'm trying to record the [file > export > "export as"] as an action. When I hit "record" and try, nothing is recorded in my action sequence, even though the jpg is correctly saved in my folder. Other methods of exporting and saving jpg/png won't work for me as I'm using a duotone document with only 2 pantone spot colors channels. **Is there a way to export/save my duotone document into a picture (for preview purposes) AND have it recorded as an action/script?**

Here's a link to an example of what my documents look like: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ckI-JVZnOjAkoBuMWJ_V_S70sNv7ef-h/view

PS: The "quick export as jpg" is recorded in the actions, but has no effect when I run the script, so it doesn't seem a viable option.

Thank you!

Comment: Allô Nicolas! You'll have better chances of getting answers if you include a screenshot of the work with your panels.

Comment: Hi again, Nicolas. I think your question should be "how can I save a multichannel image as jpg so it'd look the same as the psd" — I tried this with your file and failed but I don't have experience working with multichannel images. as I mentioned on stackoverflow, `Export As` isn't scriptable.

Comment: @Nicolas Fournier: would you find out the way? I need this too.